# Adequately Good Way to Store Variable Amounts of Data in a Single Column

Tags: sql-server, data-structures

I need to find a relatively robust method of storing variable types data in a single column of a database table.  The data may represent a single value or multiple values and may any of a long list of characters (too long to enumerate easily).  I'm wondering what approaches might work in this process.  I'd toyed with the ideas of adding some form of separator, but I'm worried that any simple separator or combination might occur naturally in the data.  I'd also like to avoid XML or snippets since in fact the data could be XML.  Arguably I could encode the XML, but that still seems fragile.

I realize this is naturally a bit of an opinion question, but I lack the mojo to make it community.

**Edit for Clarification:**

Background for the problem: the column will hold data that is then used to make a evaluation based on another column.  Functionally it's the test criteria for a decision engine.  Other columns hold the evaluation's nature and the source of the value to test.  The data doesn't need to be searchable.

Comment: Since I suspect a lot of responses to this question might take the form of 'why would you store data this way?', you may want to elaborate on what you're actually using this for. All else being equal, most of us would probably avoid storing an arbitrary data structure in a database column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the data need to be searchable? If not, slap it in a `varbinary(MAX)` and have a field to assist in deserialization.

Incidentally, though; using the right XML API, there should be no trouble storing XML inside an XML node.

But my guess is there has to be a better way to do this... it seems... ugh!

Answer (score 1):

JSON format, though I agree with djacobson, your question is like asking for the best way to saw a 2x4 in half with a teaspoon.

EDIT: The order in which data are stored in the JSON string is irrelevant; each datum is stored as a key-value pair.

Comment: So to chase the analogy, what's the appropriate saw?  The data has to be persisted somewhere and retrieved somehow.

Comment: @OldTroll: The key phrase in your clarification is "the data doesn't need to be searchable", but you may not mean what you say.  Do you need to be able to address and pull out (programmatically) individual pieces of that data to feed to some algorithm? Or is it for "human eyes only", that is, a loosely structured paragraph of text that will be read by a human?  You can use JSON to structure the data (it would  be stored as a string in the database) and JSON can be converted into bona-fide programmatic objects at runtime by most programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a "good" way to do this.  There is a reason that data types exist in SQL.

The only conceivable way I can think of to make it close is to make your column a lookup column, which refers to a GUID or ID in another table, which itself has additional columns indicating which table and row have your data.